# Select an ID from a column when comparing 2 other columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

I have a table with columns `ID`, `Valid` and `Time` that have the log of the occurrences of every access with each ID.
 From that, I made this table with `ID`, `Valid` and `Count` with this command:

`select ID,Valid, count(Valid) as Count from table1 group by ID,VALID order by ID;`

```
 ID    | Valid  |    Count   |
  1    |    0   |     5      |  
  2    |    1   |     3      | 
  2    |    0   |     8      |
  3    |    1   |     4      |  
  3    |    0   |     2      | 
  4    |    1   |     6      |
```

This table represents how many valids and invalids accesses were made, for example, ID 2 made 3 valid and 8 invalid ones.

My goal is to get the IDs that have more `0`s Valid Count than `1`s.
In this example it would be ID's `1` and `2`.

I was thinking using this new table somehow but I just can't understand how I can compare the values in the `Count` column with the `0`s and `1`s.

Maybe there's other easier way without the table I made so this the how the original `table1` looks

```
 ID    | Valid  |      Time                   |
  1    |    0   |     2012-06-28 00:00:00     |  
  4    |    1   |     2012-01-20 00:00:00     | 
  1    |    0   |     2012-08-19 00:00:00     |
  2    |    1   |     2012-07-02 00:00:00     |  
  4    |    1   |     2012-05-28 00:00:00     | 
  3    |    0   |     2012-02-07 00:00:00     | 
  ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

```
SELECT ID
FROM LOG1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(CASE VALID WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE VALID WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by ID only and calculate counts at the same time - count of `Valid=0` and count of `Valid=1`:

```
SELECT t.ID
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Valid = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountValid0,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Valid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountValid1
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY ID
) t
WHERE t.CountValid0 > t.CountValid0
```